# Database design/ ERD, is this correct?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, erd

I'm new at designing such things and I would be grateful if you tell me what's right or wrong with my drawing.

This will be the database (PostgreSQL) for a "hackernews" style website, where users can share links and upvote the good ones. Its a beginner project, I'm learning back-end.

[image: Database schema]

Answer (score 1):

I think the foreign key constraint on `userid` between `comments` and `posts` is wrong.

That would require `posts` to have a unique index on either `userid` or `(postid, userid)`, and it does not make any sense in general.

There is no need to have `userid` in `comments` – the user who wrote the post can be inferred via `postid`.

If the `userid` in `comments` refers to a different user, there should be a foreign key relationship to `users` instead.

Comment: thank you for your contribution, indeed it doesn't make sense this way...

Answer (score 0):

Good design, however you can modify a few things.

1. Comments table should point to Users table for userId column.
2. We should not have total_comments, total_votes in Posts table. You can simply get from Votes table and Comments table. Or you can have redis to access it faster. Updating Posts table for each comment and vote will be heavy